# .Net: Why we can't access to some properties of a control programmatically in winforms?

Tags: .net, winforms, properties, windows-forms-designer

.Net: Why we can't access to some properties of a control programmatically in winforms? For example, "Locked" property of a groupbox is not accessible via code. So What Possibly can I do when I want to locked it programmatically ?  Using Enabled = False will greyed out all controls within it and this is not what I wanna to be.

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Do you want to lock your control as the Designer does, or do you want to simply disable it, but without greying it out?

Answer (score 2):

Locked is not a property at all - it is just a value stored in the resource file. Locking the `Form` control yields a boolean resource value `$this.Locked` set to true.

Further some properties are attached to controls using [`IExtenderProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.iextenderprovider.aspx) similar to attached properties in WPF. For example the designer will show a propery `ToolTip` for all controls after adding a `ToolTip` control to the designer. To set the tool tip text by code you have to use

```
this.toolTip1.SetToolTip(this.button1, "A button.");
```

because there is no `ToolTip` property for controls.

And there are more mechanisms like [`ICustomTypeDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx) that cause different properties to be shown in the designer than the properties that are really defined for the control.

There is a generic solution to disable WinForms controls without graying them but unfortunately I can neither remember nor find it...

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what Locked really mean? This isn't a normal property and isn't affecting runtime anyhow, only designer. You probably should go to the problem you're trying to solve. I can assure you: the "Locked" property isn't needed for that.

Comment: Well, I do not know that whether you have developed application with Vb6 or not, but there was a control named frame which we could locked it (and also all its child controls within it) so that user could not start entring data. But the form was clear and not grey.

Comment: OK, sorry, but I still think you shouldn't do this, because this may break user's expectation on the behavior of your application.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable it!!!!

```
daveTextBox.Enabled = False
```

This will obviously change the look of the control. If you don't want to change the look of the control then override the key press event handler to do nothing.

Comment: The question is about different thing.

Comment: I disagree - my understanding of the question is that the problem is programatically locking a control

Comment: No.If you just disable it (Enabled = false) it and all its child controls within it will be grayed out. This is not what I really want.

Comment: @odiseh That's what I said in my reply - that's why I suggested overriding the key press event handler to do nothing

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, what you actually want to do is to make the controls readonly, but except for textboxes and radiobuttons this can be fairly complicated.

Below is an excerpt from some code I've written to handle something like this, but the client wanted cheap rather than perfect so I had some flexibility so it might not work for you. The method is just called by `SetControlsReadonly(gb.Controls)` (assuming a groupbox called gb).

```
Private Sub SetControlsReadonly(ByVal ctrls As Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection)
  For Each ctrl As Control In ctrls
     ctrl.Enabled = True ' first enable everything so that it'll all look the same
     If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
        CType(ctrl, TextBox).ReadOnly = True
     ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then
        CType(ctrl, Button).Enabled = False
     ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox Then
        CType(ctrl, CheckBox).AutoCheck = False
     ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is ComboBox Then
        ctrl.Enabled = False 
        if ctrl.Tag IsNot Nothing Then
            ' call method that hides the combo and instead shows a readonly textbox in the same location containing the same data
        End If
     ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is DateTimePicker Then
        ctrl.Enabled = False
     End If
     SetControlsReadonly(ctrl.Controls)
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You are missing a final `Else` block where you handle all other control types. If you don't include that, and someone puts a control on a form that your method doesn't know how to handle, it won't get disabled. -- IMO it would be better design to derive your own control classes (from the standard controls) that implement a common interface `IHaveReadOnlyProperty` (exposing a `ReadOnly` property). Your method then checks whether a control supports that interface; if so, it sets the exposed `ReadOnly` property to `false`; otherwise, it does the next-best thing, ie. it sets `Enabled` to `false`.

Comment: Well, I'm not going to say that your design wouldn't be better (especially if starting from scratch), but as I said, the client wanted cheap rather than perfect. However, I disagree regarding the `Else`, if you add an `Else` that disables everything else, you have to make sure that you don't have unexpected controls there (For example a tab control, or a groupbox that contains textboxes etc) since otherwise it wouldn't work as expected.